The uploaded app bundle targets TV devices but is not archivable
The uploaded app bundle targets TV devices but is not archivable. Archiving is enabled by default for app bundles, so this is most likely due to opting out of archiving.
Declared the TV activity changes in my manifest files
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start
